# Superfish text color in menu?

Tags: superfish

I want to have different text color for items in menu and sub-menu. Can I do that with css only, without having to modify the html, by adding a different class to items in sub-menu?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following CSS definitions:

```
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited{
    color: #ffffff;
}

.sf-menu li li a, .sf-menu li li a:visited{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

So the Menu has a white font color and the sub menu red.